# For some reason my function returns "None"? Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

Why is grepcut() returning None?

```
from termcolor import colored
from subprocess import *

def grepcut(inputRaw, grep, delimit, field):
    for line in inputRaw:
        if grep in line:
            output = line.split(delimit)[field]
            return output
        else:
            return None


def function():
    print(colored("[+] ", "green") + "Here we go!")
    inputRaw = Popen(["cat outputfile"], shell=True, stdout=PIPE, universal_newlines=True).communicate()[0].rstrip()
    var1 = grepcut(inputRaw, grep = 'grep this', field = 6, delimit = " ")
    var2 = grepcut(inputRaw, grep = 'grep this', field = 2, delimit = " ")
    print("\n")
    print(var1, var2)
    #if var1 or var2 is None:
    #   print(colored("[-] ", "red") + "Not found!!!")
    #else:
    #   print(var1, var2)

function()
```

By the way, this is the content of inputRaw:

> A B C D E F G
>   H I J grep this K L M N
>   O P Q R S T U

The output of this code is:
None None

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `grepcut` examines only the firs line: if it matches, it returns `output`, otherwise it immediately returns `None`, without going on to the next iteration.

Probably you want to remove that `else` branch and move the `return None` after the `for`.

```
def grepcut(inputRaw, grep, delimit, field):
    for line in inputRaw:
        if grep in line:
            output = line.split(delimit)[field]
            return output
    return None
```

You could even omit the `return None`, as in Python any function that terminates without an explicit `return` does return `None`, however I'd keep it, to make it clear that it's not oversight, but the function *is* expected to return `None` if it doesn't find anything.

---

Also, you are calling `communicate()` over your `Popen`, so you are getting back a *string*, not a file object; hence, you cannot iterate straight on its lines like that - iterating on a string iterates on its characters.

If `inputRaw` is indeed a string, you have to split over newlines, like this:

```
def grepcut(inputRaw, grep, delimit, field):
    for line in inputRaw.split('\n'):
        if grep in line:
            output = line.split(delimit)[field]
            return output
    return None
```

Comment: Still returns None None. I don't see how to fix this code, I'm lost.

Comment: @DonJhoe: I'd like to reproduce the issue, but your code is broken. You are missing imports and there's an extra parenthesis at the end of the `Popen` row. Post the actual code, or we aren't going anywhere.

Comment: @DonJhoe: there we go, filling in the blanks I think I found the other error.

Comment: F5 now. I fixd the missing parts. Dont forget to make a file called outputfile and change its contents so it matches my post.